# Proof of Kolmogorov-Smirnow two-sample test

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

It is well known that if  $F_N(x;ω)$ and $G_N(x,ω)$ are empirical dfs of two sequences of i.i.d r.v's and $D_{N,M}(ω) = \sup\limits_x|F_N(x;ω)-G_N(x,ω)|$, then 
$$\lim_{M,N \rightarrow \infty} P\left\{\sqrt{\frac{MN}{M+N}}D_{N,M}(ω) \le y\right\} = K(y)$$
where $K(y) = \sum\limits_{k = -\infty}^{k=+\infty}(-1)^ke^{-2k^2y^2}, (y > 0)$.

How to prove the equality?

Answer (score 0):

The proof is rather long. Check textbooks in non-parametric statistics or empirical processes. E.g. you can find the statement in A.W. van der Vaart, J.A. Wellner *Weak Convergence of Empirical Processes with Applications to Statistics* (1996), p. 365.

Comment: i have checked it already, nothing useful there...

Comment: @Ilya68, I'll check my library. Will write if I find something.

Comment: @Ilya68, I've updated the answer.